# Share node_modules binary between containers in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to run a binary npm file in a container which was installed by another container.

I understand that it is possible using a shared volume.

I have the following configuration:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  cypress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-cypress
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - cypress
    environment:
      - ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
```

Dockerfile-cypress

```
FROM cypress/base:10

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install uuid
RUN $(npm bin)/uuid
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.13

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN $(npm bin)/uuid
```

When running `docker-compose build` it fails because:

```
Step 5/5 : RUN $(npm bin)/uuid
 ---> Running in 1d86293ea47c
/bin/sh: 1: /app/node_modules/.bin/uuid: not found
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/uuid' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What is wrong in my configuration that the volume is not available in the second container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumes are shared only at runtime, not in build time.

Every **RUN** instruction works in build time, at this moment the volumes are not available.

You should put those instructions in **CMD** or an **ENTRYPOINT** instruction.
In this case, because the application is simple, we don't even need the dockerfiles.

```
version: '3'
services:
  cypress:
    image: cypress/base:10
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
    working_dir: /app
    command: /bin/sh -c 'npm install uuid && chown -R your_user_uid:your_group_uid /app && $$(npm bin)/uuid'

  test:
    image: node:10.13
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
    command: /bin/sh -c '$$(npm bin)/uuid'
```

In this case it is better if you run the test command after the execution of cypres has finished, because you have no way of knowing if the binary is already available if you run them at the same time.

I recommend you create a script in bash like this:

docker_up.sh

```
docker-compose run cypress
docker-compose run test
```

Then:

```
./docker_up.sh
```

**NOTES:**

```
chown -R your_user_uid:your_group_uid /app
```

Above code is important because you could have permissions problems working with shared volumes. Run: `echo $(id -u):$(id -g)` to get yours uids.